# How do i make my Floating Action Button(FAB) to visible in all the screen of app not just the page viewer

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to make my FAB to be visible throughout the app.

I have pageviewr and im able to display FAB in all pageViewer.
- FAB works same in all the screen so.

Even i have different activity too, i want to display in those activity too.
can any let me how do i do that.

Or do i need to add the FAB button in different activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Every activity in Android has its own content View, so you need to add FAB to each one.

But if you want to reduce duplications, you can make fab_layout.xml with `<include>` tag and use it for every layout every Activity.

Also you can implement Base activity, with providing base functionality to FAB. Or instead of parent Base activity you can implement FabHandler class and use it in each activity.